# Amazon SNS push notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

When using console to publish push notification to a endpoint, I am getting message as

```
Undefined:test
```

Where 'test' is my supplied message. How to populate this 'Undefined'. I have 'GCM' platform application created and have added an endpoint. Trying to publish to this endpoint using 'json' message generator. I don't see any subject etc. field. Just a message.

Comment: It's best to provide the code that generates this output too

Comment: I am using Amazon AWS console not using the 'api'

Comment: What does your endpoint look like? Did you follow [Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)?